# SBT: Add/enable IntegrationTest configuration in bare build.sbt

Tags: scala, build, sbt, integration-testing, bare

I have a build.sbt written in bare style, i.e. containing only `SettingKey`s.
I want to add `IntegrationTest` configuration to project, but I can't manage to do so without declaring a project and calling `configs` method on it like following:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).configs(IntegrationTest).settings(
  build.projectSettings,
  Defaults.itSettings
)
```

Simply adding `Defaults.itSettings` to build.sbt results in exception about nonexistent configuration

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'org.cassandraunit#cassandra-unit;3.3.0.2' to configuration 'it' of module com-mymodule because this configuration doesn't exist!
```

How can I both keep my build.sbt in bare style and add `IntegrationTest` config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `configs` to the `build.sbt` directly:

```
configs(IntegrationTest)
Defaults.itSettings
```

You should understand though that if you have a multi-project build, it's better to declare all projects and their common settings explicitly.